# Quadratic formula on matrices $aX^2 + bX + cI = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

## PROBLEM STATEMENT

I would like to solve the equation of type:

$aX^2 + bX + cI = 0$

for $a,b,c$ ;

where

- $X$ is some square $(N \times N)$ matrix (see footnote 1 below),
- $I$ is the identity matrix $(N \times N)$,
- $0$ is the zero matrix $(N \times N)$, and
- $a,b,c$ are some scalars

### *FOOTNOTES/CAVEATS*

1) I understand there are probably some nuances to $X$, such as invertibility or associativity.

## ATTEMPTED APPROACH

It appears that there is some analogy to solving a similar algebra problem where instead of matrices, $X$ is some root to the 2nd degree polynomial and one can simply apply the quadratic formula to get $x$. However, I am stumped on how to proceed after the substitution (see question 2 below).

## QUESTIONS

1) What area in math should I investigate to understand this type of problem better? What relevant key words should I use in searching literature?

2) If applying the quadratic formula analogy is a valid step, how do I approach the result $X = {RHS}$, where ${RHS}$ is the right-hand side of the equation that is composed of some square roots of $I$, some scalar multiples $aI, bI, cI$, etc.?

3) If there are constraints to $X$, what are they to make this solvable?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we can assume that $a\neq 0$, otherwise the problem would be trivial. We can divide the equation by $a$ and get $X^2+pX+qI=0$. Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be the two roots of the polynomial $f(t)=t^2+pt+q$. The minimal polynomial $\mu_X$ of $X$ must be
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu_X(t) &=& t^2+pt+q \\
\mbox{or} \;\;\mu_X(t) &=& t - \lambda_1\\
\mbox{or} \;\;\mu_X(t) &=& t - \lambda_2 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Therefore the solutions are either $X=\lambda_1 I$ or $X=\lambda_2 I$ or all diagonalizable matrices that have only $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ as eigenvalues. If $p^2-4q=0$, then $f$ has a single root $\lambda$ with multiplicity $2$. In this case, $X$ can be a matrix which has only $\lambda$ as its eigenvalue, and all Jordan blocks of $X$ must have size $\leq 2$.